# Can I ask a game identification question based on music?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

The [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification)tag's wiki states:

> These questions are allowed only if you have an actual screenshot,
>   video, etc. of the game you want to identify

Am I allowed to ask such a question based on a music and if yes how should I proceed with the mp3 upload? (Are there any recommanded websites?).

Comment: This is specifically why I used the term "audiovisual artifact" when calling for this exemption.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFiz I remembered reading something about it but the wiki tag did not explicitly allowed it so better be safe than sorry =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that should be specific enough. It doesn't matter where you upload the song so long as the link remains available for longer than the question does...

The sharing feature of Dropbox should be good enough.

Comment: Perfect, I used both dropbox and megaupload to be sure.

Comment: @WizLiz you mean Mega not Megaupload, Megaupload was shut down in 2012 by the US

Comment: @Memor-X Yes I mean Mega, old habits